# Get process ID and id name

Tags: process

I want a bash command that will give me from the running processes the following columns only: process id & process name and then sort them in ascending order by the second column. I cannot use sed or awk so I've been searching for a while and only thing i got was: **ps -eo pid,command** ,but 'command' doesn't exactly give me the process name. For sorting them in ascenting order it's easy i use pipelining and write sort -nk2. So, any modifications to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [manpage for the `ps` command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ps), and do

```
ps -eo pid,comm
```

Comment: I was so close, i'm new to bash, been trying to find the right command for half an hour! Thanks

Comment: If my answer helped, please "Accept" my answer.

Comment: Also worth noting:`comm` has `ucomm` and `ucmd` aliases.